# Angular JS - communication service to directive

Tags: angularjs

i cant get my head around what is the recommended way to communicate from a service to a custom directive. The custom directive is an interactive svg graphic, which on user interaction calls a method of an injected service to retrieve new data. This should happen in an asynchronous manner. I read here and there that events are in general not the recommend way to communicate in angularjs. Should I use a callback function? Or?

Thanks buddies

martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inject the service into the directive, and then the directive calls methods on the service passing in argument values as parameters.

To let a directive know that a service method has completed asynchronously, have the service method return a promise object.

http://jsfiddle.net/gGhtD/5/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
myApp.factory('myService', function ($q, $timeout) {
return {
    doSomething: function (msg) {
        var d = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function () {
            d.resolve("resolved: " + msg);
        }, 1500);

        return d.promise;
    }
  }
});

function MyCtrl($scope, myService) {
    $scope.callService = function () {
      $scope.sent = new Date();
      $scope.msg = "";
      $scope.timestamp = "";
      myService.doSomething("some value")
        .then(function (data) {
                $scope.timestamp = new Date();
                $scope.msg = data;
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. The way from directive to service is clear yet I was trying to ask how to communicate back from the service to the directive (asynchronous as the service might take some time to get the job done ...)

Comment: see my update on how to notify the directive an asyncy service operation has completed

Comment: oh thank you so much for your efforts - havent dive into it yet it seems clear that this is what i was looking for - thanks again

Comment: The original question asked about directives, yet the selected answer doesn't use a directive.  Can anyone explain this further, or answer the original question?